# Problema corriendo programas python en vscode(mac)

Tags: python, vscode, macos

Acabo de arreglar mi mac y me meti a vscode y tengo este error al correr cualquier programa en python, no se como solucionarlo, probe con python3.10 y python 2.7

> MacBook-Air-de-Lucas:Desktop lucastirado$  cd /Users/lucastirado/Desktop ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/lucastirado/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 50635 -- /Users/lucastirado/Desktop/print("holamundo").py
> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: ¿¿¿Tu archivo se llama `print("holamundo").py`???

Comment: Es que estaba probando si funcionaba con el codigo mas simple que es solo un print("holamundo") y no me lo imprime en la consola y me sale lo que puse ahi

Comment: Intenta poniéndole un nombre mas normal, main.py por ejemplo y muestra el error que te da.

Comment: no se como funciono pero cambiandole el nombre me funciono, demasiadas graciaas <3

Comment: @LucasTirado el problema es que los paréntesis y las comillas son símbolos especiales en la terminal. Para evitar este tipo de errores se acostumbra solo utilizar letras, numeros y guiones (o guiones bajos) en los nombres de archivos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.